# qtmessaging: no such file or directory (Qt-Mobility)

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-mobility

I had a problem while I'm compiling the existing example in Qt-mobility. It's a code example shows how to use messaging API in Qt for symbian. After run the program there was an error occured:

> Cannot open include file :
>   'qtmessaging.h': no such file or
>   directory

So what to do for use the qtmessaging library?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell me, what have you written in your .pro file?

Comment: TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Messaging
QT += core \
    gui
    

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += messaging
HEADERS += ListBox.h \
    SendSMS.h \
    MainPage.h \
    Messaging.loc \
    Messaging.h
SOURCES += ListBox.cpp \
.
.
.
symbian:TARGET.UID3 = 0xECFE8383
symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY = NetworkServices \
    LocalServices \
    ReadUserData \
    WriteUserData \
    UserEnvironment \
    ReadDeviceData \
    WriteDeviceData

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTMOBILITY-343) in Qt Mobility. `qtmessaging.h` is not listed as a public header file.

In later releases of Qt Mobility such as the most recent 1.0.2, `qtmessaging.h` seems to be removed completely and the examples updated to not use it. So the solution is simple: update your Qt Mobility to the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

your pro file seems to be correct.
just look at the example provided here, do cross check your profile with example one here
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-beta/quickstart.html

Comment: I just copy the compiled code in here 

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Read_and_Send_messages_in_Qt_for_Symbian. Normally it should not get any error but in my compiler it does. :S

Comment: which version of Qt mobility are you using? and in latest Qt mobility some of the header files are obsolete. so do not prefer the example which are provided there.

Comment: hey download http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html
this and use. mobility API's does't comes with Qt SDK. you should use Q mobility